# Selecting a collection does not result in exception in JPA 2

Tags: orm, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am having a bit of a trouble understanding this line of code from the book Pro JPA 2
According to the book on page 181.

> The result type of a select query cannot be a collection; it must be a
>   single valued object such as an entity instance or persistent field
>   type. Expressions such as e.phones are illegal in the SELECT clause
>   because they would result in Collection instances (each occurrence of
>   e.phones is a collection, not an instance). Therefore, just as with
>   SQL and tables, if we want to navigate along a collection association
>   and return elements of that collection, we must join the two entities
>   together.

Please consider this entities below with relationship mapping

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    ..
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Phone.class)
    private Collection<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();
    ..
}
@Entity
public class Phone {
    ..
    @OneToOne 
    private Employee employee;
    ..
}
```

Now in a test class i tried it with this test case

```
@Test
public void selectCollectionTest(){
    TypedQuery<Object> query = em.createQuery("select e.phones from Employee e where e.id = 1", Object.class);  
    List<Object> empList = query.getResultList();
    for(Object temp: empList){
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

I was expecting that an exception would be thrown but nothing is happening and I was able to select the collection?

Is this correct? Can somebody explain or clear out my understanding?

Eclipselink

Comment: You can try enabling the logging of queries sent to the database, can refer http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseLink allows this, it is an extension, the JPA spec does not support it.

It is the same as the query,

```
select p from Employee e join e.phones p where e.id = 1
```

Comment: Yes this seems so... but as a newbie in JPA, I'm just wondering why Eclipselink did this?  As a reference implmentation of JPA, I was actually thinking that it should follow the rules.  Or I might be wrong since I am just following the Pro JPA2 book.  The correct approach should be is to use JOINS? Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your query with below code by removing the where clause:

```
select e.phones from Employee e, Object.class
```

The point i am trying to make is may be your result for emp id 1 contains only single phone object.